# Same key takes two array index - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

"0012" has the same key but takes two array index, can't find the issue. Is there any encoding issues?

File content-

```
0012 2020-01-27 18:45:00
0012 2020-01-28 09:15:00
0012 2020-02-05 18:15:00
0012 2020-02-13 19:15:00
0012 2020-02-15 09:30:00
0012 2020-02-15 15:30:00
0118 2020-02-09 10:20:00
0118 2020-02-09 20:15:00
0118 2020-02-10 10:25:00
0118 2020-02-10 20:15:00
0118 2020-02-12 19:40:00
0118 2020-02-13 20:15:00
0118 2020-02-16 00:20:00
0118 2020-02-16 08:10:00
0036 2020-02-11 18:10:00
0036 2020-02-12 22:15:00
0036 2020-02-16 19:30:00
0036 2020-02-17 09:00:00
0036 2020-02-17 20:30:00
0036 2020-02-18 09:00:00
0323 2020-01-16 09:25:00
0323 2020-01-16 22:30:00
0323 2020-01-17 18:20:00
```

Scripts-

```
$filename = 'file.txt';

$array = explode("\n", file_get_contents($filename));
$array = array_filter($array);
$empArr = array();
foreach($array as $line){
    list($empId, $date, $time) = explode(" ", $line);
    $empId = (string) trim($empId);

    $empArr[$empId][] = $date . ' ' .$time;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($empArr);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output-

```
Array
(
    [﻿0012] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2020-01-27 18:45:00
        )

    [0012] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2020-01-28 09:15:00
            [1] => 2020-02-05 18:15:00
            [2] => 2020-02-13 19:15:00
            [3] => 2020-02-15 09:30:00
            [4] => 2020-02-15 15:30:00
        )

    [0118] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2020-02-09 10:20:00
            [1] => 2020-02-09 20:15:00
            [2] => 2020-02-10 10:25:00
            [3] => 2020-02-10 20:15:00
            [4] => 2020-02-12 19:40:00
            [5] => 2020-02-13 20:15:00
            [6] => 2020-02-16 00:20:00
            [7] => 2020-02-16 08:10:00
        )

    [0036] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2020-02-11 18:10:00
            [1] => 2020-02-12 22:15:00
            [2] => 2020-02-16 19:30:00
            [3] => 2020-02-17 09:00:00
            [4] => 2020-02-17 20:30:00
            [5] => 2020-02-18 09:00:00
        )

    [0323] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2020-01-16 09:25:00
            [1] => 2020-01-16 22:30:00
            [2] => 2020-01-17 18:20:00
        )

    [] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  
        )

)
```

Comment: `var_dump($empArr);` instead and see.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/6l0JzUR

Comment: @u_mulder, I tried without file reading its works fine, please let me know is there any issues with file reading or is the file somehow encoded?

Comment: What if `var_dump(array_keys($empArr))` or `var_dump($empId)` on each iteration. Some nonprinted symbol is obviously in your file, I presume BOM.

Comment: After var_dump the empId in each iteration - `array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "0012"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "0012"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "0118"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "0036"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "0323"
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
}`

Comment: `[0]=> string(7) "0012"` that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Try eliminating all non-printable characters:

```
$empId = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/', '', trim($empId));
```